# What is the benefit of scaling the hyperparameter C of an SVM?

Tags: hyper-parameters, regularization, support-vector-machine

Please read the following [page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_scale_c.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-svm-scale-c-py) of the Sklearn documentation.

The figure shown there (see below) illustrates why C should be scaled when using a SVM with 'l1' penalty, whereas it shouldn't be scaled C when using one with 'l2' penalty.

[image]

The scaling however does not change the scores of the models examined within the GridSearch. So what exactly is this scaling-step good for?